# Calculate the integral of $f(z) =(z^2+1)\sin(\frac{iz}{z-i })$ on positively orientated $ |z|=2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the integral of $f(z) =(z^2+1)\sin(\frac{iz}{z-i })$ on positively orientated $ |z|=2$.

First I looked at the singularity $z_{0}=0$. When I calculated the limit  of $f(z) $ at 0 it seems that it is 0 and then the integral would be 0? I think I did something wrong here.

Comment: Why do you think that $z = 0$ is a singularity? There is an essential singularity at another point inside the circle $|z| = 2$ (so if you calculate limits at that point along different directions, you'll get different values), but instead of calculating the residue there, it's simpler to calculate the residue at infinity, where $f$ just has a pole.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
f(z)&=&i(z^2+1)\sinh(\frac{z}{z-i})=i(z^2+1)\sinh(1+\frac{i}{z-i})\\
&=&\frac i2(z^2+1)\bigg(e^{1+\frac{i}{z-i}}-e^{-1-\frac{i}{z-i}}\bigg)\\
&=&\frac i2(z^2+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg[e\frac1{n!}\bigg(\frac{i}{z-i}\bigg)^n-e^{-1}\frac1{n!}\bigg(-\frac{i}{z-i}\bigg)^n\bigg)\\
&=&\frac i2(z^2+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ei^n-e^{-1}(-i)^n}{n!}\frac{1}{(z-i)^n}\\
&=&\frac i2[(z-i)+2i]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ei^n-e^{-1}(-i)^n}{n!}\frac{1}{(z-i)^{n-1}}\\
&=&\frac i2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(ei^n-e^{-1}(-i)^n)}{n!}\frac{1}{(z-i)^{n-2}}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(ei^n-e^{-1}(-i)^n)}{n!}\frac{1}{(z-i)^{n-1}}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-i}$ is
$$ \frac i2\frac{(ei^3-e^{-1}(-i)^3)}{3!}-\frac{(ei^2-e^{-1}(-i)^2)}{2!}=\frac{-5+7e^{2}}{12e}. $$
So
$$ \int_{|z|=2}(z^2+1)\sin(\frac{iz}{z-i })dz=2\pi i\frac{-5+7e^{2}}{12e}=\frac{-5+7e^{2}}{6e}\pi i. $$

Comment: $z = i$ is not a removable singularity. You can't eliminate an essential singularity by multiplying by a polynomial.

Comment: @Maxim, you are right. I will fix it.

Comment: The line where you have $(i/2) \sum + i \sum$ should be $(i/2) \sum - \sum$.

Comment: @Maxim, yes, you're right. Thank you again.